# I want to join a flexed <section> with a <p>

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to be able to join my `<section>` and the `<p>` underneath. Here is my HTML and CSS code:

```css
#projects {
  background: linear-gradient(#5db7de, #4e9bbb);
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.project-tile {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #113f53;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#project-1 {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="projects">
  <h3 id="intro-projects">This are my HTML/CSS Web Responsive projects</h3>
  <br />
  <section class="project-img" id="project-1">
    <a href="https://survey-form.freecodecamp.rocks" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/survey-form-background.jpeg" />
    </a>
  </section>
  <p class="project-tile">SURVEY FORM</p>
  <div id="space_bottom"></div>
</div>
```

My goal:

[image]

You can see how my image text and pictures are separated unlike the "My goal" picture.

Comment: You have to put two tags in one div tag and then assign display flex to that div.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by applying `margin-top: 0` to `.project-tile` and applying `display: block` to `img`.